# Passing commands through to other classes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm just starting out with WPF, and trying to do things the MVVM way (following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) great article).

I have a central manager class that ALL view models will need to interact with. I implemented this using a singleton, so I have my singleton class:

```
public class FakeManager
    {

        private FakeManager() {}

        static FakeManager instance;
        public static FakeManager Instance
        {
            get { return instance ?? (instance = new FakeManager()); }
        }

        ...
    }
```

And in my view models I interact with this like so:

```
public ICommand TriggerChannelChange
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(() => FakeManager.Instance.SetupChangeRequest(_hardwareItem), () => true);
    }
}
```

My question is - is there a better way? I know of the event mediator pattern, which is commonly used in WPF to send messages between ViewModels, is that something that would be better here? I guess my issues with what I've done are the fact that I'm tightly coupled to the FakeManager, plus it feels a little clumsy.

Thanks

Comment: "return new" in a property getter sounds always bad to me

Comment: Hi @blindmeis. You mean the ICommand? That seems to be very standard among the MVVM implementations I've seen. For sending commands, I think it's fine.

Comment: Added another comment re: this to the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I agree with blindmeis that creating a new command in a property getter violates the general expectations of a property getter, including:

- that they are very lightweight
- that they return the same object unless it is replaced (probably via a setter)

But that's an aside point, so I won't labor it.

As for your question, I would suggest looking into a service pattern, whereby you define an interface for the service and then your view models take a dependency on that service. The ways they can obtain the service are many and varied. You might want to start simple with the [service locator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), or maybe look into [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) or [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Re: property getters. I agree with all you say, I wouldn't expect a prop getter to return me a new object normally. I think it's this way so that the XAML view can easily bind to it, as shown in that CodeProject link. But I'll look into fixing that down the line.

Comment: Re: The suggestion. I quite like that. I'm using DI heavily in a MVC web app, so this would allow me to remove the coupling and inject the service where it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

A publish/subscriber pattern that you already mentioned would be my preferred approach here. Prism has a good implementation with the `EventAggregator`.

The benefits of setting it up like that is, besides code decoupling, that you can reason about your problem domain in a much cleaner way. You can have your viewmodels as independent 'islands' that send well defined (in domain language) messages through the system. The viewmodels dont have to know anything about how other parts act upon them. These messages are a conceptually integral part of the system and deserve to be modeled as such. It also eases testing and much simplifies the task to introduce new features and fix bugs that are interacting with those messages.

Comment: Cheers. I've only seen these used between ViewModels in my small foray into WPF/MVVM, so I was wary of going down this road. But it does seem to fit the need quite well.